# Why can't I send a value to a UILabel on another ViewController?

Tags: xcode, swift, uilabel

I'm just trying to send text to a UILabel on another ViewController via a segue:

```
let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewViewController
controller.detailViewLabel.text = "Hello!"
```

But when the segue is performed, `detailViewLabel` is `nil` every time.

However, if send the string to a new var of type `string`, then assign `detailViewLabel.text` to the new string in `viewDidLoad`, it works fine.

For example, this works fine:

```
var detailViewLabelText: String!

@IBOutlet weak var detailViewLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    detailViewLabel.text = detailViewLabelText
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Why can't I directly send the string to the `text` property of the `UILabel` via a segue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outlets in view controllers aren't connected until the first time the view is loaded.  Views are loaded when the `view` property of the UIViewController is accessed for the first time.

So, your code should work if you force the view to load before trying to set the text on the label, e.g.

```
let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewViewController
let _ = controller.view
controller.detailViewLabel.text = "Hello!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just initialize the string that you're trying to send outside of the class, then it's available to all classes. That's not really professional but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to Daniel Hall, but I set the data to a variable and then, once the view loads, I set the label.text to the variable.